# Determine the caller process of a Win32 function

Tags: windows, win32-process

Is there any way to determine that which process has called a Win32 Function. Actually I need to hook a few functions and in addition I also need to determine that which process has called this function. I am done with hooking functions like `FindNextFile()` and winsock functions `send()` and `receive()` using MS Detours but the problem is with later part i.e. determining the caller process. Kindly Help.

Comment: If you already hooked e.g. send(), you must have installed a hook handler named as send_handler() or similar thing, in send_handler(), you can call GetModuleFileName() to get executable image name, or GetCurrentProcessId() to get host process's PID. I doubt whether this is really what you're asking here.

Comment: Well If I am able to call `GetCurrentProcessId()` which gives me Process ID, then I can get the ProcessName as well. This exactly solves my problem. But could you please elaborate some more on hook handler i.e. `send_handler()` and how to use it.

Comment: I remember detours ships with lots of samples, there's a sample which demonstrate how to hook winsock, you can just add GetCurrentProcessId() in send_handler() (detours may have different name for the handler).

Comment: Changing behavior based on the name of the process will lead to problems that are very difficult to debug. You should not be hooking processes other than your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hook will run in the context of the calling process, so it may simply call [GetCurrentProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or a similar function that returns what you need to know about the process.

Comment: Yes offcourse Adrian !! I got the idea after further research. Actually, my complete solution lies in that I want to know whenever a process calls `FindNextFile()`. That could happen by: (i)"Setting a system wide hook" OR (ii)"Hooking all of the running processes". So could you tell me which one is better/easier and how to know the caller Process in that context.

Comment: @Faheem:  I don't understand your follow-up question, possibly because I've never worked with Detours.  You should look as see if your new question has been address on Stack Overflow.  If not, start a new question.